# using one pipe for communication between multiple devices

Tags: racket, pipe

I'm currently writing an project in Racket where in I need to communicate with a few (simulated) devices. I'm using the Racket pipes for this. Devices can read from the pipe, and write a generated answer on the pipe. The steward is also able to see the generated-answers on the pipe and write commands on the pipe.

Devices can write messages to the pipe by the following code:

```
File1:   
(#%require "communication.rkt")

(write-string message output)
(flush-output output)
```

communication exports the input and output port:

```
File2: 
(define-values (input output) (make-pipe #f))
```

The steward reads messages from the pipe:

```
File3: 
(#%require "communication.rkt")
(if (char-ready? input) 
    (read-string 1 input)
```

When de steward tries to read a string from the pipe, 'char-ready' always returns #f.. But i'm sure that the devices write something on the pipe. Does anyone see my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Possibly buffering -- maybe the "steward" needs to `flush-output`, too? 2. If possible, instead of using ports and pipes, it would probably be cleaner and simpler to use Racket channels? 3. By the way, I'm just curious why you're using `#%require` not `require`?

Comment: I'm not certain of this, but I think the issue is that when you `require` a module, it instantiates it specifically for the `require`-ing module and so the writer and the reader each have their own instance of the module - they're not looking at the same pipe. You could give each of the writer/reader modules parameters for the pipes, then have some other module instantiate the pipe and pass the input and output pipes to the other modules. I don't know how you'd do this in a scenario where there are runtime boundaries with multiple devices instead of module boundaries however.